# Month name from Month Numbers in android

Tags: java, android, datepicker, monthcalendar

I have a problem with **converting the month number into month Name** that is if month number 1 or 2 its returning March only. But for 1 it should return Feb right ? Previously i had this same problem for one day but next day it automatically worked i don;t How? But today again its showing like this I need some help to **FIX** it

```
public static String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
    String monthName = "";

    if (monthNumber >= 0 && monthNumber < 12)
        try {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
            //simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e != null)
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return monthName;
}
```

if monthNumber 1 or 2 
in this statement

```
monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

its returning **Mar** (March) only. But for the other numbers its working fine. Can any one of help me out of this ?

Comment: try this link http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29

Comment: you should have tagged this as a java question also...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue appears because February has less than 30 days.

For example, running this today (30.04.2014) :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

returns

```
Sun Mar 02 14:52:28 CET 2014
```

You should add in your code before setting month :

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Answer (score 15):

Following code for returning the right month name.

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
int monthnum=5;
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthnum);
String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());

Log.e("",""+month_name);
```

Here the output is **June**

Comment: this is the correct solution, i am using something similar in my app.

Comment: thanks... my code also same this... if i give 5 it will work fine the problem with 1 and 2 only... and i am using my code for past 3 months it worked find. I think this is the second time it showing wrong result for 1 and 2

Comment: Could you please set your system time to 31 of March and then call your sequence of code? you might have a surprise...

Answer (score 3):

in Kotlin

```
fun getMonthByNumber(monthnum:Int):String {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val month_date = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM")
        c[Calendar.MONTH] = monthnum-1
        return month_date.format(c.time)
    }
```

thank you